# Error to find 'residuals.coxph' function from 'survival' R package

Tags: r, survival

I'm trying to use 'residuals.coxph' function, but it isn't found.

`residuals.coxph(fit4,type="scaledsch")`

I have downloaded the newest version (3.5-7) from 'survival' package, and used other functions (including 'coxph', to obtain 'fit4'). The error is the following:

`Error in residuals.coxph(fit4, type = "scaledsch") :  could not find function "residuals.coxph"`.

Can anyone explain me why the function isn't being found?

Comment: what if you just use  `residuals()`  instead of `residuals.coxph()` the function should be able to fine the appropriate method for this

Comment: As @Mike says, that's not how you use that function. See the example at the bottom of the [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/survival/html/residuals.coxph.html).

Comment: Thank you! Using `residuals()` instead of `residuals.coxph()` worked for me.